# Auto complete from database using CodeIgniter (Active Record)

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter, activerecord, autocomplete

I have a form on my website in which one is able to submit a cat. The form contains inputs such as "Name" and "Gender", but I am just trying to get the auto completion to work with the "Name" field. Here is what my jquery looks like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: '/Anish/auto_cat'
});
});
```

Here is what my model looks like:

```
  public function auto_cat($search_term) {
    $this->db->like('name', $search_term);
    $response = $this->db->get('anish_cats')->result_array();
    // var_dump($response);die;
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function auto_cat(){
  $search_term = $this->input->get('term');
  $cats = $this->Anish_m->auto_cat($search_term);
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
</head>

<h1>Anish's Page</h1>
<form action="/Anish/create" method="POST">
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Name</label><input id="tags" type="text" name="name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Age</label><input type="text" name="age">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Gender</label><input type="text" name="gender">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Species</label><input type="text" name="species">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Eye Color</label><input type="text" name="eye_color">
  </div>
    <div>
    <label>Color</label><input type="text" name="color">
  </div>
    <div>
    <label>Description</label><input type="text" name="description">
  </div>
    <div>
    <label>marital status</label><input type="text" name="marital_status">
  </div>
  <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary span1">Add cat</button>
</form>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>  
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Species</th>
        <th>Eye Color</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Marital Status</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($cats as $cat):?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['name']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['gender']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['age']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['species']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['eye_color']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['color']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['description']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo ($cat['marital_status']);?><br/>
          </td>
          <td>  
          <form action="/Anish/edit" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($cat['id']);?>" name="Anish_id_edit">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-info">Edit</button>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td>
          <form action="/Anish/delete" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($cat['id']);?>" name="Anish_id">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am stuck. In my console, I am able to see this output when I type the letter 'a' if I uncomment the var_dump in my model:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "13"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Anish"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["species"]=>
    string(3) "Cat"
    ["eye_color"]=>
    string(5) "Brown"
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "Black"
    ["description"]=>
    string(7) "Awesome"
    ["marital_status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Anish"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(2) "fe"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["species"]=>
    string(2) "fe"
    ["eye_color"]=>
    string(2) "fe"
    ["color"]=>
    string(2) "fe"
    ["description"]=>
    string(2) "fe"
    ["marital_status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "17"
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["age"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["species"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["eye_color"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["color"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["description"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["marital_status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Matt"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(6) "Female"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["species"]=>
    string(6) "ferret"
    ["eye_color"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "pink"
    ["description"]=>
    string(5) "Chill"
    ["marital_status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

This is an image of my table:
[image: This is an image of my table:]

I appreciate all of the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if it helps:

```
<?php
    #controller function
    public function auto_cat(){
        print_r ( $this->model->search_auto_cat($_REQUEST['term']) );
    }

    #model function
    function search_auto_cat($term){
        $data   = array();
        $rs     = $this->db->select('name as label, name as value, id', false)->or_like('name', $term)->or_like('last_name', $term)->or_like('id', $term)->limit(20)->get('anish_cats');
        //print_r($this->db->last_query());
        if($rs->num_rows() > 0 ){
            $temp   = $rs->result_array();
        }else{
            $temp   = array();
            $temp[0]['label']  = "No results found";
            $temp[0]['value']  = "";
            $temp[0]['id']     = "0";

        }
        $data   = json_encode($temp);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

it means it is working but the problem is that you only need data from one column. 
so in model

```
public function auto_cat($search_term) {
$this-db->select('name'); 
$this->db->like('name', $search_term);
$response = $this->db->get('anish_cats')->result_array();
// var_dump($response);die;
return $response;
 }
```

}

and in controller.

```
public function auto_cat(){
      $search_term = $this->input->get('term');
     $cats = $this->Anish_m->auto_cat($search_term);
      print json_encode($cat);
}
```

I hope this will help your answer.